# How to increase input box size from right to left

Tags: jquery

How to increase  input box size from right to left

```
$('#search').live('focus', function () {

    $(this).animate({
        width: ($(this).width() + 60) + 'px'
    }, 300);

}).live('blur', function () {

    if ($(this).val() == '') {

        $(this).animate({
            width: ($(this).width() - 60) + 'px'
        }, 300);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

> ```
>         <div style="position:absolute; float:right; right:160px; top:-14px;">
>           <input class="boxHomeFilterButton" id="searchInInstitudesButton" style="width:100px; padding-left:15px;"
> ```
>
> placeholder="Hizli Ara" onfocus="focusSearch(this);"
>   onblur="bluurSearch(this);"/>

and this

> ```
>    function focusSearch(e) {
>         $('#searchInInstitudesButton').animate({
>             'margin-left': '-=60px',
>              width : 160,
>             "opacity": "9"
>         }, 200);
>         //e.style.width = "115px";
>         //e.style.backgroundColor = '#62b930';//'#666';
>         document.getElementById('searchInInstitudesButton').removeAttribute('placeholder');
>     }
>
>     function bluurSearch(e) {
>         //e.style.backgroundColor = '#528834';
>         $('#searchInInstitudesButton').attr("placeholder", "Hızlı Ara");
>         $('#searchInInstitudesButton').animate({
>             'margin-left': '+=60px',
>             width: 100,
>             "opacity": "4"
>         }, 200);
>         $('#searchInInstitudesButton').style.opacity = "0.5";
>     }
> ```